# Resolving urls without file extensions when using PHP server without Apache

Tags: php

I'm trying to start work on a PHP development site locally (on my work Mac Mini).  I'm using PHP 7.1 and have been able to start work, using the built-in PHP web server.

`php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t www/`

The issue I'm having is resolving requested URL's (without .php extensions) that exist as .php files in the web directory.

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = refinance
```

Needs to resolve this

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = refinance.php
```

I know this can be done with apache mod_rewrite, either using the httpd.conf file or a local .htaccess file.  I'm trying to avoid using apache and would rather PHP handle serving these files. 
I have a basic router.php that I found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/taking-advantage-of-phps-built-in-server/). It seems that the specific code in the router.php could help:

```
// if requesting a directory then serve the default index
$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (empty($ext)) {
    $path = rtrim($path, "/") . "/" . DIRECTORY_INDEX;
}

// If the file exists then return false and let the server handle it
if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $path)) {
    return false;
}
```

I'm stuck on the `if (empty($ext))` conditional. It seems that inside that `if` I should be able to take the REQUEST_URI and add a php extension and have it resolve but I can't make it work.

Comment: this sounds very much like an XY Problem. What is the goal for that? What do you need that for? What's wrong with mot_rewrite or a router (you'll need at least one .php for a router anyway)?

Comment: You cannot achieve this without Apache unless you create a folder structure with nothing but `index.php` files and sub-folders with more `index.php` files. If you wish to support direct requests for `refinance.php` still then just create that file parallel to the folder named `refinance`. Overall, this solution will quickly become a maintenance nightmare and if you plan to one day run your app on a real web server then it's much better to just get Apache or NGINX working on your computer. You are basically shooting your foot and then attempting to walk; it might work but it's not pretty.

Comment: Does $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] not solve this?